# Join three tables to get a combined result

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have three tables in the db and in which i need to perform a query to fetch combined data.

[image]

I expect this result as in the screenshot.

Query can be in mysql, ms sql, etc.. i will convert it to use it in my BQ table.

I can only achieve it by joining 2 tables and union all with another table but that is too heavy and has large number of columns.

Is this be possible with a single query?

Query:

```
select *, '' t_name, '' t_value, '' date1 from tableA a 
join tableB b ON a.ID=b.ID
UNION ALL
select ID, '' type, '' name, '' rect, '' m_name, '' m_value, '' date1, *
FROM tableC
```

Comment: Please see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors to improve your question.

Comment: Why can't you get the same data from joing all three tables? I.e select * from TableA a inner join TableB b on a.Id = B.Id inner join TableC c on a.Id = c.Id?

Comment: Yes @DeWetvanAs, i tried but when using this and other queries i'm getting more records instead 4 rows like factorial combinations.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `Union`-query that you already have. And what do you mean with large number of columns? Or do you mean rows?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Its difficult to understand your problem without seeing the output you are getting when using the inner joins, however, it seems like you might need to use a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this statement:

```
     select a.ID, a.TYPE, a.name, a.rect, b.m_name, b.m_value, b.date1, ' ' as t_name, 0 as t_value, ' ' as date
       from TableA a,
            TableB b
      where a.ID = b.id 
      union all 
     select a.ID, a.TYPE, a.name, a.rect, ' ' as m_name, 0 as m_value, ' ' as date1, c.t_name, c.t_value, c.date
       from TableA a,
            TableC c 
      where a.ID = c.id;

ID TYPE NAME  RECT    M_NAME M_VALUE    DATE       T_NAME    T_VALUE DATE     
-- ---- ----- ------- ------ ---------- ---------- ------ ---------- ----------
A1 A    ABC   ABC123  oil    157        12/05/2023                 0           
A2 B    ABC1  ABC1234 gas    112        12/06/2023                 0           
A1 A    ABC   ABC123           0                   train1        869 12/05/2023
A2 B    ABC1  ABC1234          0                   train2        867 12/08/2023
```

Thank you.